# 'Manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition' when uploading Outlook add-in manifest

Tags: office365, outlook-web-addins

When uploading a manifest file for an Outlook add-in that implements [add-in commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt267546.aspx), I get the following error:

> Something went wrong
>
> This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. The element 'CustomTab' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Label' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides'. List of possible elements expected: 'Group in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides'...

However, the `Label` element is a valid child of the `CustomTab` element. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: Make sure the `Label` element appears **after** all `Group` elements inside the `CustomTab` element.

Office 365 recently enabled additional schema validation on manifest files, and due to the way the schema is defined for the `CustomTab` element, it expects `Label` to come after.

In other words, a manifest with this `CustomTab` element will trigger the error:

```
<CustomTab id="TabCustom1">
  <Label resid="customTabLabel1"/>
  <Group id="group1">
    <Label resid="groupLabel1"/>
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="uilessButton1">
      <Label resid="uilessButtonLabel1"/>
      <Supertip>
        <Title resid="uilessButtonSuperTipTitle1"/>
        <Description resid="uilessButtonSuperTipDesc1"/>
      </Supertip>
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="uilessButtonIcon1-16"/>
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="uilessButtonIcon1-32"/>
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="uilessButtonIcon1-80"/>
      </Icon>
      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <FunctionName>buttonFunction1</FunctionName>
      </Action>
    </Control>
  </Group>
</CustomTab>
```

Changing it to this will resolve the error:

```
<CustomTab id="TabCustom1">
  <Group id="group1">
    <Label resid="groupLabel1"/>
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="uilessButton1">
      <Label resid="uilessButtonLabel1"/>
      <Supertip>
        <Title resid="uilessButtonSuperTipTitle1"/>
        <Description resid="uilessButtonSuperTipDesc1"/>
      </Supertip>
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="uilessButtonIcon1-16"/>
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="uilessButtonIcon1-32"/>
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="uilessButtonIcon1-80"/>
      </Icon>
      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <FunctionName>buttonFunction1</FunctionName>
      </Action>
    </Control>
  </Group>
  <Label resid="customTabLabel1"/>
</CustomTab>
```